# balena does it automatically restart the service

Tags: balena

I trying to compile grpcio inside the container. However I have noticed occasionally the container will restart itself. Therefore I loose all the progress I have made.

I was wondering is it normal for the service to be periodically restarted? Also what is the default policy for restarting it? i.e. is it every x amount of hours or what

I am running balenaOS 2.83.21+rev1. It's a managed image I believe since I downloaded the image by adding a device via the dashboard.